# Python CSV, Combining multiple columns into one column using CSV

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to figure out a way to combine all the columns in a csv I have into one columns.

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = [' '.join([row[0], row[1]])] + row[2:]
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

This worked to combine the first two columns, but I've been having trouble trying to loop it and get the rest of the columns into just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just pass `row` to `.join` because it's an array.

```py
import csv
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = [' '.join(row)] # <---- CHANGED HERE
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```